# Pushing a generated file to github from with a Go application

Tags: go, github

I'm working in an application that generates files, and I would like to push those files to a github repo. Is that possible to do from within the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the package [go-git](https://github.com/src-d/go-git). It allows you to perform git clone/commit/push operations. It can clone a tree in-memory too without requiring disk access.

From the the [commit example](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/master/_examples/commit/main.go) is a sample add/commit:

```
_, err = w.Add("example-git-file")
CheckIfError(err)

commit, err := w.Commit("example go-git commit", &git.CommitOptions{
        Author: &object.Signature{
            Name:  "John Doe",
            Email: "john@doe.org",
            When:  time.Now(),
        },
})
```

Comment: the go-git repo has moved here [https://github.com/go-git/go-git](https://github.com/go-git/go-git)